# VBA Excel cannot paste FormulaArrey " unable to set formulaarray property of the range class"

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I try to paste formula into cell.

```
wsModel.Cells(4, 3).Formula = "=MMULT(B11:AD11;TRANSPOSE(B8:AD8))"
```

But code returns me error "Run-time error '1004' application-defined or object-defined error"

```
wsModel.Range("C4").FormulaArray = "=MMULT(B11:L11;TRANSPOSE(B8:L8))"
```

Tried to use FormulaArray but that also does not work " unable to set formulaarray property of the range class"

Note: This formula works when I manually enter it in as an array formula

Comment: Change the `;` to `,`.

Comment: @BigBen Omg, what a silly mistake. Thank you